# Write Post data to file with PHP

Tags: php, http, post, text

I need to post data using the code below, to php file that will save it in a text file.
I just don't know how to create the php file to receive the data below and save it in a text file.
as simple as possible.

```
try {  
    // Add your data  
    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);  
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringData", "12345"));  
    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("stringData", "AndDev is Cool!"));  
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));  

    // Execute HTTP Post Request  
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);  
    String responseText = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()); 
    tv.setText(responseText);             
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
} catch (IOException e) {  
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block  
}
```

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Simple as:

```
file_put_contents('test.txt', file_get_contents('php://input'));
```

Comment: <?php
$content = $_POST['content'];
$file = "text.txt";
$Saved_File = fopen($file, 'w');
fwrite($Saved_File, $content);
fclose($Saved_File);
?>

Comment: If you want to get the value of one particular key and save it, then yes. If you just want to dump the raw POST data (which doesn't have to be key value pairs - it could be binary data, for example) then the 'php://input' stream will read it. The question was vague and asked for "as simple as possible".. well it doesn't get much simpler.

Comment: also, `file_put_contents` performs the fopen, fwrite and fclose in one hit - easier to use and to read.

Comment: Thanks hamish, i know its just so hard when you're new to php.

Comment: feel free to upvote the answers if they've been helpful. Thats how you say thanks.

Comment: Hamish, you're the man, i can't believe one simple code did the trick, thanks alot.

Comment: add a third parameter `FILE_APPEND` to `file_put_contents` to append request data to the file instead of overwriting all the time.

Comment: explanation please

Comment: i was totally astonished by knowing  that  "this can also be done!" . never knew it before!

Answer (score 23):

1) In PHP, to get POST data from an incoming request use the $_POST array.  The POST array in PHP is associative, which means that each incoming parameter will be a key-value pair.  In development it's helpful to understand what you're actually getting in $_POST.  You can dump the contents using printf() or var_dump() like the following.

```
var_dump($_POST);
```

-- or --

```
printf($_POST);
```

2) Choose a useful string-based format for storing the data.  PHP has a serialize() function, which you could use to turn the array into a string.  It's also easy to turn the array into a JSON string.  I suggest using JSON since it's natural to use this notation across various languages (whereas using a PHP serialization would somewhat bind you to using PHP in the future).  In PHP 5.2.0 and above the json_encode() function is built-in.

```
$json_string = json_encode($_POST);

// For info re: JSON in PHP:
// http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php
```

3) Store the string in a file.  Try using fopen(), fwrite(), and fclose() to write the json string to a file.

```
$json_string = json_encode($_POST);

$file_handle = fopen('my_filename.json', 'w');
fwrite($file_handle, $json_string);
fclose($file_handle);

// For info re: writing files in PHP:
// http://php.net/manual/en/function.fwrite.php
```

You'll want to come up with a specific location and methodology to the file paths and file names used.

**Note: There's also the possibility of getting the HTTP request's POST body directly using $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA.  The raw data will be URL-encoded and it will be a string that you can write to a file as described above.**

Comment: I just need to know, how my php file on my server should look like" <?php  ?>

Comment: Put <?php ... ?> tags around Hamish's answer and you're good to go.

Comment: i did and it worked, thanks alot, once i understand it alittle bit more then i'll use your way. Thanks for the fast answers

Comment: From http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php -- php://input allows you to read raw data from the request body. In case of POST requests, it preferrable to $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA as it does not depend on special php.ini directives. Moreover, for those cases where $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is not populated by default, it is a potentially less memory intensive alternative to activating always_populate_raw_post_data. php://input is not available with enctype="multipart/form-data".