# Apache2 Server POST?

Tags: apache, file, post

I have installed Apache on my raspberry pi. Currently it's possible to get files by just sending a 'GET' to my raspi (http://192.168.178.131/test.json).
Now I wanted to send a 'POST' to update the file. I tried different things but unfortunelty all doesn't worked.
I read that it's not even possible with Apache. I would need some sort of php file, which manages the file upload.
Is this correct?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apache2 is a HTTP server, which runs the HTTP protocol. Long story short, HTTP is a web protocol thought to serve files: a client issues a request to a server, and the server sends back the corresponding file.

Apache2 does typically this: it receives a request, and either responds with the appropriate file, or forwards the request to another service. It cannot create or edit files on the system, except for its log files.

This is why you need something else (a web application) to store the data for you. There are many ways to create a web app, and PHP is indeed one way to do this.

Now, from your post I have the impression that a web server is not the right tool  for what you want to do. It looks like you want to use your raspberry as a remote storage. If that is the case Raspberry made a cool [tuto](https://www.raspberrypi.com/tutorials/nas-box-raspberry-pi-tutorial/) on how to do it... This may help.

Otherwise if you really want to upload a file though a POST request, maybe this post will help: [Write Post data to file with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742898/write-post-data-to-file-with-php)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I just set up a PHP which handles the POST. Thanks!